# Why is my AWS Amplify API list query not returning all my items

Tags: react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I am trying to use the AWS Amplify API list query in my react-native project. I know my DynamoDB table has an item in it because the list query works in the AWS AppSync Console but when I use the query in my project, I am returned an empty output.

I have tried to call the query in my project like this:
`const users = API.graphql({ query: queries.listUsers });`

But when I run it and log 'users' out to the console, this is what the log looks like:
`{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}`

This is the query that was written by Amplify based on my schema:

```
export const listUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListUsers(
    $filter: ModelUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        userName
        bio
        streak
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I believe my issue stems from the fact that I am not calling listUsers with any parameters.

In my AWS AppSync console, this is the query I use to correctly return a list of items out:

```
query MyQuery {
  listUsers {
    nextToken
    items {
      id
      bio
      createdAt
      name
      streak
      updatedAt
      userName
    }
  }
}
```

I know one solution would be to simply create a new query in my project that doesn't take any parameters, but if Amplify generated listUsers with parameters, I feel like they must be important. Should I simply create a new query with no parameters or should I be using the generated one?

Answer (score 1):

API.graphql is an asynchronous operation. Did you try prepending "await"?

Your statement would be as follows...

const users = await API.graphql({ query: queries.listUsers });

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing. When I go thru the amplify async API and I fire a query :

```
try {
    const data = await API.graphql({
      query: listFullTags,
      authMode: isAuthenticated ? "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" : "AWS_IAM",
    });
```

I get 15 hits

Do I a query via an index field (profile_id in my case) I get 28 returned (which is right)
So I use this query

```
const retObject = await API.graphql({
      query: tagsbyProfileId,
      variables: { userID: userId },
      authMode: isAuthenticated ? "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" : "AWS_IAM",
    });
```

Same table same data.  ---Very strange -> I use that workaround (last code) it is good for me. I use Amplify 12.1.1